# How to approach multiple parsing of large amount of data (800k records)?

Tags: c#, .net, large-data

I have a desktop application that validates certain CSV files.
I'm given this CSV file which I need to parse and validate against multiple business rules. Those business rules can apply to every record in particular, or they can check integration bonds that have the range concerning all of the records in the file. The file is almost 800k records long.

Here's how I approach the problem currently:

1. I upload the csv file and convert every line to a custom object (a for loop is used here) that I end up storing in a list. This point takes 3 to 6 seconds usually, so I don't consider it a problem.
2. I pass the list to a validator class, which thanks to StructureMap gets all the business rules as separate classes.
3. I iterate through the business rules. My first business rule throws an exception like this:

> The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0xa4234fc8 to COM context 0xa42350f0 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.

I understand that this can be hidden, but I don't want to hide the error, I want to understand what can I do to make the code more efficient. I already eliminated all thrown Exceptions in the code, and it does work better.

For each record I run the following code inside a business rule:

```
var mandatoryFields = GetFieldsWithAttribute<MandaroryFieldAttribute>(package);

foreach (var field in mandatoryFields)
{
    var fieldValue = field.GetValue(package, null).ToString();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fieldValue))
        continue;

    var errorMessage = GetErrorMessage(package.RowNumber, field.Name,
        field.GetAttributeForPackage<CsvFieldNameAttribute>().Name);

    if (FailedResults.Contains(errorMessage))
        continue;

    FailedResults.Add(errorMessage);
}
```

Since there are a lot of fields - I decided to validate fields using custom attributes, to make the process more generic. System.Reflection is used inside the two extension methods: GetAttributeForPackage and GetFieldsWithAttribute.

4. Write a report summarizing the validation into a text file.

The problem, as I see it, is that I have to parse every single record, on for some rules all the records for one rule.

I do not have experience in parsing large amount of data. Can anyone suggest an approach on how to handle this?

Comment: Why not read the file either line by line or in bunches of, lets say, 1.000 lines?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé because "business rules ... can check integration bonds that have the range concerning all of the records in the file"

Comment: If you store them in a list then you can process up to N records.  Murphy's law demands that sooner or later you get a CSV file with N+1 records.  Odds are 100% at SO.  Project > Properties > Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.  You don't prefer it.

Comment: Can you pinpoint a rule that throws the error?

Comment: @Evk Ok, thats a point. But that is only a problem if the logic isn't adjusted accordingly

Comment: Why you are not getting out of memory during step 1? At step 3 your memory shouldn't be significantly growing anymore since you already loaded everything at step1...

Comment: For as long as problem is abstract you will get "abstract" answers. Try to change the way you are processing it: 1) don't keep all data in memory, index it or use easy to index intermediate format (e.g. database),  2) if you can load all data, then maybe you need only to use less memory-greedy validation. Details are important and you haven't provided them.

Comment: Added more details, as requested. @HansPassant it was already unticked.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that may help you:

- Since you have large file I suggest you use [Memory-mapped files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx)
  .This enable programmers to work with extremely large files

  Since   you have lot of records to validate ,you could consider using
  threading or parallel programming(Tasks).This way the execution will
  be faster.

  I guess you are using StreamReader.ReadLine to read every
  line.

Comment: Actually I use File.ReadAllLines to read the file in whole, then convert every row with a for loop.